# Insert the Sections in Tableview in ios

Tags: ios

My App is Retrieve the Facebook Friends Birthday List in Month vise(Ex:August,September.....July).
  I Retrieved the Friends List and Displayed in Device using Table view.but,Display the Recently Celebrated Friends List in new Sections in this List.
  How to insert the sections in this Tableview?

Comment: DO you know how to implement `UITableView`... ?

Comment: ya.I know.but,I don't know insert the additional sections in tableview

Answer (score 0):

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return ArryForFriendSection.count;
}
```

For more information [read This official Documentation.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDataSource/numberOfSectionsInTableView%3a)

Comment: I know this Concept.but how to insert the additional section for Recently Celebrated List